# Grails external config location for deployed war

Tags: grails, configuration

I have an external config file that I use in my development environment in order to specify the datasource of my grails application. I import the external file in my config.groovy using the following lines :

```
   grails.config.locations = ["classpath:${appName}-config.groovy",
                           "file:./${appName}-config.groovy"]
if (System.properties["${appName}.config.location"]) {
    println("found")
   grails.config.locations << "file:" + System.properties["${appName}.config.location"]
}
```

This works as expected and well. However I have an issue when the application is deployed as a war file. The locations as to where the config file is are hardcoded in config.groovy as above. My requirement is to allow customers to specify the location of their own configuration file.

I'm stuck with this as the locations are hardcoded in config.groovy before the war file is built. I don't know how I'd go about letting a customer modify these values. I don't want to have to build a different war file for each customer containing the location of their configuration file.

Is there a method of changing these values? Or perhaps its reasonable that I have a hardcoded value where all customers should put their configuration files? I'd be interested to see if anyone has any suggestions?

Comment: You already have that with the `${appName}.config.location` system property.

Answer (score 0):

I have the next working config. So, it may be useful for you.

```
// This condition may be rewrited in the Groovy style
final configbase = System.properties.'aaaaa.configbase' ? System.properties.'aaaaa.configbase':"${userHome}/.aaaaa/"
grails.config.locations = [
        // Standart Grails config
        "classpath:${appName}-config.properties",
        "classpath:${appName}-config.groovy",

        // Redhat Openshift
        "file:${userHome}/app-root/data/.aaaaa/${appName}-config.properties",
        "file:${userHome}/app-root/data/.aaaaa/${appName}-config.groovy",

        // Based on System property -Daaaaa.configbase
        "file:${configbase}/${appName}-config.properties",
        "file:${configbase}/${appName}-config.groovy",
]
```